# Not able to enable filter on top row in excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am getting error while enabling autofiltermode using powershell on excel file. This is the script  i am trying

```
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible=$True
$workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Trash\filter.xlsx')
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq 'sheet1'}
$worksheet.autofiltermode=$true


$workbook.Save()
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Error:

```
Unable to set the AutoFilterMode property of the Worksheet class
At line:1 char:1
+ $worksheet.autofiltermode=$true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

This is what i am expecting(attachment)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0DS8.png

Comment: does `$worksheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData()` make any difference?

Comment: Try `$worksheet.EnableAutoFilter = $true`

Comment: $worksheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData() gives following error
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: $worksheet.EnableAutoFilter = $true doesn't work. I don't see filter enabled after running this. Neither it gives any error

Answer (score 2):

FYI:

[`Worksheet.AutoFilterMode` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.autofiltermode?view=vsto-2017#microsoft-office-tools-excel-worksheet-autofiltermode)

> **Remarks**
> You can set this property to false to disable filtering (that is, to remove the filter drop-down arrows), but you cannot set it to true. To enable filtering and create a filtered list, use the AutoFilter method of a Range object, or use the AutoFilter method of a NamedRange object.

Comment: how can i use the range in powershell? sorry i am new to this

Comment: Read the second half of the comment from the link "To enable filtering and create a filtered list, use the AutoFilter method of a Range object, or use the AutoFilter method of a NamedRange object."

Comment: I am not able to create the object of Range or NamgedRange. getting error "new-object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range"